# What is the replacement for a blinking text in a web page?

Tags: html, css, deprecated

I have heard that using blinking text in a page to get user's attention is not a good practice.

What is the alternative for that?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the user's attention in this case?

Comment: Blinking text is sooooo 1990's xD

Comment: Wether or not is a good practice, it doesn't seem quite right to remove an HTML feature that was nearly universal. Language designers shouldn't have a part on what should/shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Text that doesn't blink is a good alternative.

If you have to rely on blinking text or flashing images to get your users to look where you want, then your website probably has some serious design flaws. Here are some articles with some tips on good web design.

- [10 principles of effective web design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/01/31/10-principles-of-effective-web-design/)
- [9 essential principles for good web design](http://psd.tutsplus.com/designing-tutorials/9-essential-principles-for-good-web-design/)

Comment: For some web application with very importants alerts not only blinking may be useful but also sound. I would not like to die because the hospital ER system designer thought blinking was bad style.

Answer (score 10):

```
<marquee>SCROLLING TEXT!!!</marquee>
```

Alright, maybe just stick with **bold** or

> blockquotes

or *italics* or

#### headings...

Comment: in my opinion marquee is a annoying at least as much as "blink" and it only brings memories of sites made in early years of internet

Comment: Marquee is not a recommended one.

Comment: `<marquee>` was a joke, please god don't use it

Comment: @Sohnee - I am not sure how you came to the conclusion that you should "stick a h1 tag in the middle of a paragraph" from my post or use the `<i>` tag, I simply listed other options he can choose for emphasis and styling (which also happen to be semantically correct if you check the source...)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to emphasise a piece of text semantically, use:

```
<em>this is important</em>
```

or

```
<strong>this is important</strong>
```

I'm not recommending these for their styles, but for their meaning. You can apply whatever style you want to these elements to make them stand out however you like.

Answer (score 4):

Start here!

```
.alternativeToBlink {
  font-family:
  font-size:
  color:
  background-color:
  border:
  text-decoration:
}
```

Comment: +1 I totally agree. You should use CSS or proper markup (i.e. h1, h2...)

Answer (score 3):

HighLighted Text (stuff that doesn't link). Probably, that portion of the text is highlighted for a period of time, and fades out.

You can use Javascript Libraries to get that kind of effect.

Answer (score 2):

Just some thinking about the opposites here: If you have something on the page that should catch the user's attention, does that not mean that you ALSO have things on the page that should NOT catch the user's attention?

Perhaps you should remove things that take away from the most important message?

This kind of minimalism is popular in big-fonted and margin-rich "web 2.0" sites. So one could say it is a BLINK replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using a Javascript highlight behavior, think about the goal of the page. If you want someone to notice one thing on the page, perhaps that's the only thing that should be there. Consider removing other elements to draw attention to what you need them to see.

If all else fails, there's always the Ajax-based blink tag: http://cheese.blartwendo.com/web21-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

blinking bullit in CSS is not the good choice. But you could use some JQuery plugin or flash to make some text pulsating with colors, or fading in and out

Comment: I do not recommend to use blinking text!

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the validation:

- `text-decoration: blink;` is still valid CSS
- You could do it the [AJAX way](http://cheese.blartwendo.com/web21-demo.html) ;)

Having elements which blink can definitely be very annoying to your users, but, as with everything, don't pay too much attention to the rules which include the word "never". Right now in my operating system there are blinking icons to alert me to things which need my attention. In whatever web application you're making, you could have a similar situation.

Just remember to use it sparingly...