# How to display blinking text over an image in Corona SDK?

Tags: image, text, sdk, coronasdk

I seem to have some serious problems here - I'm trying to display an image and transition it in, then have blinking text over it at the bottom.

```
function Splash()
   local item = display.newImage("SplashImage.png")
   item.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
   item.y = display.contentHeight*0.5
   item.alpha=0
   transition.to(item, {time =1500, alpha=1, onComplete=Blink})
end

-- blinking text

function Blink()
   text = display.newText("This is Blinking Text", 100, 100, "Arial", 22)
   text.x = display.contentWidth/2
   text.y = display.contentHeight/1.2
   text.alpha=0
transition.to(text, {time =1500, alpha=1, onComplete=Blink2})
end

function Blink2()
   if (text.alpha > 0) then                  [--THIS IS THE LINE THAT IS BROKEN APPARENTLY]
      transition.to(text, {time=1500, alpha=0})
   else
      transition.to(text, {time=1500, alpha=1})
   end
end

txt_blink = timer.performWithDelay(500, Blink2, 0)
```

Code breaks with error "Attempt to index upvalue 'text' (a nil value)"

I'm a total noob at this so be gentle!

Comment: In all seriousness, I would try and avoid [blinking text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211044/what-is-the-replacement-for-a-blinking-text-in-a-web-page) if possible.

Comment: be aware that you are using "text" as a global variable. It's not a good practice even if you implement the functionality. When your app grows, using global variables in this way will lose control and lose readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, when Blink2() is called it looks for an object "text" which is not created in that time. So you should check first if there is an object called "text" or not. Here is the new blink2() function for you:

```
function Blink2()
    if text ~= nil then
        if (text.alpha > 0) then
            transition.to(text, {time=1500, alpha=0})
        else
            transition.to(text, {time=1500, alpha=1})
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: No, Splash function is called by an onComplete after the previous image fades in and out.

Comment: You're a genius dude. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you.

```
--> Pre-declare the text variable
local blinkingText

--> Create the splash function
function Splash()
    local item = display.newImage("SplashImage.png")
    item.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    item.y = display.contentHeight*0.5
    item.alpha=0
    transition.to(item, {time =1500, alpha=1, onComplete=createBlinkingText})
end

--> Create the blinking text
function createBlinkingText()
    blinkingText = display.newText("This is Blinking Text", 100, 100, "Arial", 22)
    blinkingText.x = display.contentWidth/2
    blinkingText.y = display.contentHeight/1.2
    blinkingText.alpha=0
    transition.to(blinkingText, {time =1500, alpha=1, onComplete=startBlinking})
end

--> Start the blinking
function startBlinking()
    if (blinkingText.alpha > 0) then
        transition.to(blinkingText, {time=1500, alpha=0, onComplete=startBlinking})
    else
        transition.to(blinkingText, {time=1500, alpha=1, onComplete=startBlinking})
    end
end

--> Call the splash function
Splash()
```

I changed a couple variable names so you can better understand them.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that your function Blink2 has been asked to access a variable "text" which has not been previously declared as a table/object.  Put a:

```
local text = {}
```

at the top and it should solve your problem.