# Blinking Text If checkbox is checked to true

Tags: c#, html, jquery, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create when user check checkbox to yes(true) in Index Page Emergency column needs to flash text something like Emergency
But unfortunately I try couple of methods but unsuccessfully.
Here is so far what I did

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Doctor Full Name - CODE
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Patient Full Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date and Time
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Emergency
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var obj in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Doctor.Firstname @obj.Doctor.Lastname @obj.Doctor.Code</td>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Patient.FirstName @obj.Patient.LastName</td>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.DateAndTime</td>
                        @if(obj.Emergency == true)
                        {
                            <span class="blink_me">Emergency</span>
                        }


                        <td class="text-center">
                            <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                <a asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p> No Admission Patient exists.</p>
    }


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        (function blink() {
            $('.blink_me').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink);
        })();
    </script>
}
```

I am posting image here to see what happened and example of what I am looking for

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ywoubLj5/2/)

[image]

Any idea what I made wrong?

Comment: Blinking text is not the most accesible thing out there. Depending on your user base you could get into problems.

Comment: Why you think that ?

Comment: Check the [Web Accessibility Initiative](https://www.w3.org/WAI/)

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you talking about

Comment: Check [What is the replacement for a blinking text in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211044/what-is-the-replacement-for-a-blinking-text-in-a-web-page)

Comment: i think you problem is Emergency  is aleays false

Comment: Yes, I see that and I correct this right now

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the question, not only on an external site like jsFiddle. Note that if you click the `<>` button, it opens an interface much like jsFiddle's, where you can put your code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this is all relevant code which I have nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css:

```
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

and html:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach (var obj in Model)
                {
                    string fadinOutClass = "";
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Doctor.Firstname @obj.Doctor.Lastname @obj.Doctor.Code</td>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.Patient.FirstName @obj.Patient.LastName</td>
                        <td width="25%">@obj.DateAndTime</td>
                        @if(obj.Emergency == true)
                        {
                            fadinOutClass="elementToFadeInAndOut";
                        }


                        <td class="text-center">
                            <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                <a asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary mx-2 @fadinOutClass">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a asp-route-Id="@obj.Id" asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-danger mx-2 @fadinOutClass">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

What do you want Flash to do? According to the code I gave you, the buttons flash